# Experimental $g^{(2)}$ measurement

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, quantum-optics

I'm in need to find a paper/book that discusses how to obtain the [$g^{(2)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_coherence) correlation of a certain emitter when using an [Hanbury Brown Twiss interferometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect) (HBT) with two single photon avalanche diodes (APD). This means recovering $g^{(2)}$ from data obtained with, possibly, different quantum efficiencies on each APD and different noise background levels.

For some reason I can't find it. Any recommendation or link will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- In the [Becker & Hickl TCSPC handbook](https://www.becker-hickl.com/literature/documents/flim/the-bh-tcspc-handbook/) you can probably find answers to all of your questions, for example:

  - Pages 141-150 deal with many different real-world detector effects. I can already telly you that different quantum efficiencies on the APDs doesn't change $g^{(2)}$, because it's normalized away.

    Pages 567-570 deal with coincidence measurements in picosecond time scales.

    Pages 597-610 are about time-resolved single molecule spectroscopy.

  The book was intended to be an extended manual for Becker & Hickl products, that's why it has many concrete examples about instrumentation and software in it. Furthermore, to ensure their products find the right markets, it explains many of the standard methods commonly used in biology. It should be comprehensible to anyone with a science background.