# Is anti-bunched light necessarily sub-Poissonian?

Tags: photons, quantum-information, quantum-optics

It is well-known that sub-Poissonian photon statistics and light anti-bunching normally occur together, since both effects may be considered as a manifestation of photon streams being 'regular enough'.

Zou & Mandel (PRA 1990) provided an example of a sub-Poissonian light which is bunched.

That is, the statement "sub-Poissonian implies anti-bunched" is false.

Does any counterexample exist for the statement "anti-bunched implies sub-Poissonian statistics?"

Thank you!

Comment: I think the definition of *anti-bunched" is "not Poissonian"

Comment: what are your definitions of "anti-bunched" and "sub-Poissonian" here? Because the two things are often defined as the same thing.

Comment: sub-Poissonian means that the photon number statistics satisfy $\Delta n < \sqrt {\bar n}$. That is, the standard deviation of the photon number is smaller compared to the Poisson distribution case (with the same mean photon number).

Being anti-bunched means that $g^{(2)}(0)<1$, where $g^{(2)}$ denotes the second-order correlation function of the light. @glS

Comment: @MocaAoba I see, that makes sense. I'd suggest you to edit the post to also include those definitions, as they make it easier to answer the question. By the way, have you seen [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/623204/58382)? I suppose the answer to your question might simply be the observation $g^{(2)}(0)=\frac{\langle n^2\rangle-\langle n\rangle^2}{\langle n\rangle^2}=1+\frac{\sigma_n^2-\langle n\rangle}{\langle n\rangle^2}$

Comment: @glS I see... That answer indeed answers my question. Thanks.  (And that answer also implies that, in some sense, merely comparing $g^{(2)} (0)$ to 1 is not the "correct" definition for light being (anti)bunched.)